# Simple Inner Join and Index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a simple inner join Query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.guid, t.post_title 
FROM wph3_posts t 
INNER JOIN wph3_postmeta tr 
ON t.ID = tr.post_id AND tr.meta_value LIKE '%>Washing</a>%' AND t.post_status = 'Publish' 
ORDER BY t.post_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

When I do an MySQL explain I get the following output:

```
|id|select type|table|type|possible_key|key|key_len|ref|rows|extra|
:--|:--|:--|:--|:--|:--|:--|:--|:--|:--|
|1|SIMPLE|t|ALL|PRIMARY, myKey|NULL|NULL|NULL|29859|Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|
|1|SIMPLE|tr|ref|post_id|post_id|8|y345435_wp946.t.ID|6|Using where; Distinct|
```

The "myKey" index was just created and is an index of **wph3_posts with (ID, post_status)**

The key is still being ignored though and is showing as NULL for the keys being used.
The query takes roughly **1.4230** to execute which I'd really like to narrow down.

EDIT: Upon swapping round my key order: **wph3_posts with (post_status, ID)** I can then get **myKey** to be used as an index but unfortunately it doesn't do much for performance.

Comment: Can you specify `tr.meta_key` instead of searching all meta values?

Comment: Unfortunately no. What we need to look for is stored under "item_html" meta_key and we then have to search through the whole key value for what we need. The key value is a bunch of HTML content that we are checking to see if it contains specific items. This wasn't planned out initially so this is what we are left with for searching. I'm caching the response which mitigates the time it takes but I'd like the initial check to be quicker if possible.

Comment: So why can't you use `tr.meta_key = 'item_html' AND tr.meta_value LIKE '%>Washing</a>%'`?

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I didn't cop that and missed that. Thank you! That did a big decrease on time to perform the query and lowered it to 0.2171 seconds!

Comment: LIKE patterns that begin with `%` are expensive, anything that can cut them down should help.

Comment: I actually worried that the % was the cause I was already hitting it the fastest way possible, glad to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for pointing this out to me.

In my original query, I was searching through all meta values instead of telling it to search for meta values stored under the specific key I was looking for.
So **`tr.meta_key = 'item_html' AND tr.meta_value LIKE '%>Washing</a>%'`** was the key to this.

My updated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.guid, t.post_title 
FROM wph3_posts t 
INNER JOIN wph3_postmeta tr 
ON t.ID = tr.post_id AND tr.meta_key = 'item_html' AND tr.meta_value LIKE '%>Washing</a>%' AND t.post_status = 'Publish' 
ORDER BY t.post_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

This cut the query time down to 0.2171 seconds which is a very nice improvement over what it was.

Comment: Further improvement on `postmeta` may be possible with the tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta)